# Android Push Notification

Tags: android, push-notification

I refered link [a link](http://www.vogella.de/code/de.vogella.android.c2dm/codestartpage.html) to develop Push Notification but while running it show me the UI (main.xml). What should I do to create Push Notification (C2DM server) sample app?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you are asking, sorry

Comment: Hai ollie i have added a link(source code link) in my question right.The sample code is there i copied those source code and made sample push notification app. while running the project its running(no error in source code) but in an Emulator it displays UI(textview and button) only suppose i clicked button no reaction.what should i do to run sample push notification?I hope U will now understand! if u know sample push notication code for android please post here

Comment: you can check this tutorial <http://life-optimized.blogspot.com/2012/03/android-push-notifications-using-urban.html>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the best C2dM documentation I've seen. It's in the form of a tutorial and it both explains how everything works, and provides sample code.

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html

GCM is outdated. FCM comes as a replacement for GCM.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uuiuVDb2bug

Comment: Ollie whether It's Working Properly

Answer (score 12):

Here's the documentation for Firebase Cloud Messaging Service that replaces C2DM and GCM: 
  https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Comment: Here is a good tutorial for GCM: <http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/>

Comment: Your link appears broken, but it is a thorough tutorial at http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Answer (score 10):

C2DM has been officially deprecated as of June 26, 2012,instead of c2dm you can use android cloud to device management service(GCM)

Answer (score 0):

**Free and easy method:**

If your target user base is not large(less than a 1000) and you want a free service to start with, then Airbop is the best and most convenient.

[Airbop Website](http://www.airbop.com/) 
It uses Google Cloud Messaging service through its API and is provides a good performance. i have used it for two of my projects and it was easy implementing it. You can easily build your sample app with it.

Services like Parse([Parse website])[2](http://www.pushwoosh.com/) and Urbanship are excellent but paid and provide an entire deployment stack and not just the push notifications thing.

If only push service is your target, Airbop will work fine.

I haven't used [Pushwoosh](http://www.pushwoosh.com/), but is also a great choice. It allows push to 1,000,000 devices.