# How can I receive a notification on my phone when a website gets updated?

Tags: android

I'm making an app for android and I wanted it to be able to receive a notification when ever a website changes it's content.

I'm fairly new to app development and have no idea where to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**If you don't own the websites**:

I think you would need a program (in your server or computer) querying the websites that you care about and comparing their HTTP info for update date. And if you see any updates, send notifications from your server to the app (using [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)).

Other methods for knowing the last time it was modified: [check last time website updated](http://www.computerhope.com/tips/tip30.htm)

**If you do own the websites**:

you could use [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) every time you update to push a notification from the server.

And here they talk about it and even list some tutorials : [GCM in stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9479472/android-push-notification)

Vogella's tutorial : [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html)

Comment: what if I did own the website?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must register your users with your website with a unique key. for e.g. GCM(Google cloud messaging registers user when the start the app.)

For detailed information about `GCM` go through [this link](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)

Note: GCM is free to use.

Then if Your website gets updated you must send a push notification to all registered users and in your mobile application you must register a broadcast receiver to receive that notification and display in your desired UI.